# Stop Windows Implementation Library warnings during compilation

Tags: visual-studio, wil

How can I stop VS2022 from displaying hudreds of warnings that are not in my own source? These are Windows Implementation Library warnings:

Snippet:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State   Details
Warning C26432  If you define or delete any default operation in the type 'class wistd::unique_ptr<wchar_t [0],struct wil::function_deleter<void (__stdcall*)(void *),&void __stdcall CoTaskMemFree(void *)> >', define or delete them all (c.21).  Meeting Schedule Assistant  D:\My Programs\2022\MeetSchedAssist\packages\Microsoft.Windows.ImplementationLibrary.1.0.231216.1\include\wil\wistd_memory.h    783     
Warning C26432  If you define or delete any default operation in the type 'class wistd::unique_ptr<wchar_t [0],struct wil::cotaskmem_secure_deleter>', define or delete them all (c.21).    Meeting Schedule Assistant  D:\My Programs\2022\MeetSchedAssist\packages\Microsoft.Windows.ImplementationLibrary.1.0.231216.1\include\wil\wistd_memory.h    783     
Warning C26447  The function is declared 'noexcept' but calls function 'operator()<void>()' which may throw exceptions (f.6).   Meeting Schedule Assistant  D:\My Programs\2022\MeetSchedAssist\packages\Microsoft.Windows.ImplementationLibrary.1.0.231216.1\include\wil\wistd_memory.h    576     
Warning C26432  If you define or delete any default operation in the type 'class wistd::unique_ptr<void,struct wil::process_heap_deleter>', define or delete them all (c.21).   Meeting Schedule Assistant  D:\My Programs\2022\MeetSchedAssist\packages\Microsoft.Windows.ImplementationLibrary.1.0.231216.1\include\wil\wistd_memory.h    524     
Warning C26432  If you define or delete any default operation in the type 'class wistd::unique_ptr<struct wil::details::event_watcher_state,struct wistd::default_delete<struct wil::details::event_watcher_state> >', define or delete them all (c.21).    Meeting Schedule Assistant  D:\My Programs\2022\MeetSchedAssist\packages\Microsoft.Windows.ImplementationLibrary.1.0.231216.1\include\wil\wistd_memory.h    524     
Warning C26477  Use 'nullptr' rather than 0 or NULL (es.47).    Meeting Schedule Assistant  D:\My Programs\2022\MeetSchedAssist\packages\Microsoft.Windows.ImplementationLibrary.1.0.231216.1\include\wil\wistd_functional.h    391     
Warning C26477  Use 'nullptr' rather than 0 or NULL (es.47).    Meeting Schedule Assistant  D:\My Programs\2022\MeetSchedAssist\packages\Microsoft.Windows.ImplementationLibrary.1.0.231216.1\include\wil\wistd_functional.h    385     
Warning C26440  Function 'wistd::function<void __cdecl(void)>::__as_base' can be declared 'noexcept' (f.6). Meeting Schedule Assistant  D:\My Programs\2022\MeetSchedAssist\packages\Microsoft.Windows.ImplementationLibrary.1.0.231216.1\include\wil\wistd_functional.h    294     
Warning C26432  If you define or delete any default operation in the type 'class wistd::__function::__base<void __cdecl(void)>', define or delete them all (c.21).  Meeting Schedule Assistant  D:\My Programs\2022\MeetSchedAssist\packages\Microsoft.Windows.ImplementationLibrary.1.0.231216.1\include\wil\wistd_functional.h    216     
Warning C26440  Function 'wistd::__throw_bad_function_call' can be declared 'noexcept' (f.6).   Meeting Schedule Assistant  D:\My Programs\2022\MeetSchedAssist\packages\Microsoft.Windows.ImplementationLibrary.1.0.231216.1\include\wil\wistd_functional.h    141     
Warning C26440  Function 'wil::err_exception_policy::OK' can be declared 'noexcept' (f.6).  Meeting Schedule Assistant  D:\My Programs\2022\MeetSchedAssist\packages\Microsoft.Windows.ImplementationLibrary.1.0.231216.1\include\wil\result_macros.h   7257        
Warning C26429  Symbol 'ph' is never tested for nullness, it can be marked as not_null (f.23).  Meeting Schedule Assistant  D:\My Programs\2022\MeetSchedAssist\packages\Microsoft.Windows.ImplementationLibrary.1.0.231216.1\include\wil\result_macros.h   7236
```

There are so many it is causing my intellisense to keep crashing.
[image]

Comment: Project > Properties > Code Analysis > General > "Enable Microsoft Code Analysis" = No.

Comment: @HansPassant but that switches it off for the whole project. This never happened before. I think it is since I updated the WIL Nuget package. I have settings to stop testing external headers. But these seem to still be checked. Or is my assumption wrong about this setting?